# Using Spatie Roles Library In GraphQl Query ( Rebing ) Always Returns NULL

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-permission

###### The Files I'm Using :

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQl\Query\User;

use App\GraphQl\Traits\UserTrait;
use App\Models\User;

use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Query;
```

###### The GraphQl UserRolesQuery File :

```
use Closure;


class UserRolesQuery extends Query
{
    use UserTrait;

    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'user',
    ];

    public function type(): Type
    {
        return GraphQL::type('UserType');
    }

    public function args(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => [
                'name' => 'id',
                'type' => Type::int(),
//                'rules' => ['required'] validation
            ],


        ];
    }

    public function resolve($root, array $args, $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo, Closure $getSelectFields)
    {
```

###### The Resolve Function Where I Expect To Return User Role Names

```
        $user = User::find($args['id']);
        $result =  $user->getRoleNames();
        return $result;


    }

}
```

###### I Expect The `$user->getRoleNames();` To Return The User Roles Name .. But it always returns `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

```
$user->getRoleNames();
```

this function return Collection and if you want just get role names ,
you must change return type

```
public function type():Type
{
    return Type::listOf(Type::string());
}
```

also in resolve

```
$result =  $user->getRoleNames()->toArray();
```